# Spring boot intercept service methods

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

I have this service managed by spring boot

```
@Service
public class SystemSecuredServiceBean implements SystemSecuredService {

    @Override
    public <S extends BaseEntity> S save(S s) {           
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to intercept before the method invoking, Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Aspect-oriented Programming (AOP) with AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop) which is directly integrated in the core Spring framework.

In your case the `@Before` annotation seems appropriate.

You can read [Spring AOP AspectJ @Before Annotation Example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-aop/aspectj-before-annotation-example/) for details.